# Python parallel execution of a function with multiple arguments of integers and arrays, inside a nested loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, nested-loops

I want to execute a function inside two nested loops using parallel processing. The function takes one integer (i), 1D array (C) and 2D arrays (A & B). The integer is iterated over some values while the arrays are kept constant.

I tried two approaches:

1. 3 loops with the 3rd loop to iteratively execute the function.
2. 2 loops and the 3rd loop is replaced with starmap() multiprocessing function.

Both approaches compile without errors. But the output matrix B2 from starmap() approach does not match with output B1 from regular loops. Also, the one with starmap() seems to take more time than regular loop. Below is the code.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def function(i, A, B, C):
    B[i,:] = B[i,:] + A[i,:] + 50*C[i]
    return B

if __name__ == '__main__':

    L1 = 10
    L2 = 2
    A = np.zeros([100, 100]) + 5
    C = np.zeros([10]) + 10

# Regular 3 nested loops
    start = time.time()
    B1 = np.zeros([100, 100])
    for f in range(L1):
        for t in range(L2):
            if (f>4):
                for i in range(f):
                    res = function(i, A, B1, C)

                B1 = res

    print("Elapsed time: ~",f"{((time.time() - start)):.2f}","s")

# 2 nested loops and 1 parallelized
    start = time.time()
    B2 = np.zeros([100, 100])
    for f in range(L1):
        for t in range(L2):
            if (f>4):
                argslist = [(i, A, B2, C) for i in range(f)]
                #res = []
                with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
                    res = pool.starmap(function, argslist)

                B2 = res[0]

    print("Elapsed time: ~",f"{((time.time() - start)):.2f}","s")

    print(B1)
    print(B2)
```